# How to declare a variable that conforms to a protocol with a specific associated type?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol for diffing two models:

```
protocol Differ {
    associatedtype Model
    func diff(oldModel: Model, newModel: Model)
}
```

and a concrete class that implements the protocol:

```
class CabinModelDiffer: Differ {
    func diff(oldModel: CabinModel, newModel: CabinModel) { }
}
```

where the model is just a class with some properties:

```
class CabinModel { //some properties... }
```

Finally, I have a higher-level class which contains a differ:

```
class CabinManager {
    var differ: CabinModelDiffer?
}
```

which I can create and assign a differ to:

```
let manager = CabinManager()
manager.differ = CabinModelDiffer()
```

My problem is, I would like to be able to assign a mock differ to the manager for unit testing, like this:

```
manager.differ = MockCabinModelDiffer() //Error: Cannot assign value of type
```

where my mock differ implements the protocol and uses the same associated type as the actual differ:

```
class MockCabinModelDiffer: Differ {
    func diff(oldModel: CabinModel, newModel: CabinModel) { }
}
```

I cannot figure out how, or if it's even possible, to declare the differ variable in my manager so that it will accept any type that conforms to the `Differ` protocol and uses `CabinModel` as its associated type.

```
class CabinManager {
    var differ: ??? //what type to declare this as?
}
```

Comment: Either declare the `differ` property as `var differ: Differ` or make `MockCabinModelDiffer` subclass `CabinModelDiffer`

Comment: Declaring as `Differ` results in error: `Protocol 'Differ' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.`

Comment: Subclassing may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to use associated type in the protocols, you have to create the class as generic.

```
protocol Differ {
    associatedtype Model
    func diff(oldModel: Model, newModel: Model)
}

class CabinModel {
}

class CabinModelDiffer: Differ {
    func diff(oldModel: CabinModel, newModel: CabinModel) { }
}

class CabinManager<T: Differ> where T.Model == CabinModel {
    var differ: T?
}

let manager = CabinManager<CabinModelDiffer>()
manager.differ = CabinModelDiffer()

class MockCabinModelDiffer: Differ {
    func diff(oldModel: CabinModel, newModel: CabinModel) { }
}

let manager1 = CabinManager<MockCabinModelDiffer>()
manager1.differ = MockCabinModelDiffer()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking to restrict the CabinManager to only accept Differ's that use CabinModels. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is useful. It does help with unit testing. Thanks!